# Desplazar elementos en arreglo en java (matriz y arrays)

Tags: java, array, matrices

Quisiera saber si pueden ayudarme amigos.

Supongamos que tenemos un array  en java, y que se encuentra bien chida de 4x4.

[6 0 0 7]

me gustaría que quedase de la siguiente forma, apartando los ceros para la izquierda y numeros a la derecha.
[0067]

y poder realizar esto para todos los tamaños del array, es decir que si el array fuese
[000050006000] me sirviese tambien el codigo.

He realisado un búcle for enalsado con un while, pero el problema se encuentra al hayar dos valores 0 seguidos.

Comment: Amigos, no me han entendido. Yo quiero que los ceros queden al lado izquierdo y que por orden queden en el lado derecho los numeros. No se el tamaño de la matriz... por ejemplo, me dan este arreglo(90000), yo quiero que tras azplicar el algoritmo, quede así (000009). no quiero una lista, sino un arreglo normal de enteros int[].

Answer (score 2):

Hay una librería denominada Arrays que te ayuda a ordenar de menor a mayor un arreglo. Para ello tienes que importarlo y hacer lo siguiente:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numeros = {0, 7, 2, 0, 0, 6, 7, 2, 1};
    Arrays.sort(numeros);
}
```

Esto permite que ordene el arreglo y cuando lo recorres y lo imprimes se ve de la manera como lo necesitas. Espero que sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando Java 8 o superior puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
/*agregas elementos*/
list.add(1);
list.add(3);
list.add(2);
list.add(1);
list.add(5);
list.add(9);
list.add(8);
/*imprimes los items desordenados*/
list.stream().forEach(System.out::print);
/*ordenas los items*/
list.sort( (x,y) -> x.compareTo(y));
/*imprimes los items ordenados*/
list.stream().forEach(System.out::print);
/*pasas la lista a un array*/
int x[] = list.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
/*imprimes los items*/
for (int i : x) {
    System.out.print(i);
}
```

> Este es el resultado: 132159811235891123589

Si estas usando Java 7 o inferior te recomiendo que veas metodos de ordenamiento(Burbuja entre otros)

Answer (score 0):

O usando algún método de ordenamiento, en este caso usé burbuja.

```
for(int i=0;i<numeros.length-1 ; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<numeros.length-1 ; j++){
            if(numeros[j]>numeros[j+1]){
            int temp = numeros[j+1];
            numeros[j+1] = numeros[j];
            numeros[j] = temp;

        }
        }
    }
```